# TYPO3 7.6 - tx_news 4.2.1 - no detail name in realurl?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl, tx-news

The realurl config with tx_news works fine for me, but I have one problem. I dont need the detail-name in the address.

www.domain.org/news-list/**news-detail**/test-news-name-here/

and now i dont need the "news-detail".

Here the PHP code realurl.php

```
<?php


$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['addRootLineFields'].= ',tx_realurl_pathsegment';
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'] = array( 
'pagePath' => array(
    'type' => 'user',
    'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
    'spaceCharacter' => '-',
    'languageGetVar' => 'L',
    'expireDays' => '3',
    'rootpage_id' => 1,
    'firstHitPathCache'=>1
),
'init' => array(
    'enableCHashCache' => TRUE,
    'enableCHashCache' => 1,
    'respectSimulateStaticURLs' => 0,
    'enableUrlDecodeCache' => 1,
    'enableUrlEncodeCache' => 1
),
'preVars' => array(
    array(
        'GETvar' => 'L',
        'valueMap' => array(
            //'de' => '0',
            //'en' => '1',
        ),
        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
    ),
    array(
        'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
        'valueMap' => array(
            'nc' => 1,
        ),
        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
    ),
),

'fileName' => array(
  'index' => array(
    'sitemap.xml' => array(
      'keyValues' => array(
        'type' => 1234,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),

'fixedPostVars' => array(
    'newsDetailConfiguration' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
            'valueMap' => array(
                'detail' => '',
            ),
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
            'valueMap' => array(
                'News' => '',
            ),
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),

        array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
            'lookUpTable' => array(
                'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'title',
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                    'strtolower' => 1,
                    'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                ),
                'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                'autoUpdate' => 1,
                'expireDays' => 180,
            ),
        ),
    ),

    '6' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
    // For additional detail pages, add their uid as well
    //'13' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
    //'22' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
    //'4' => 'newsTagConfiguration',
    //'4' => 'newsCategoryConfiguration',

),
'postVarSets' => array(
    '_DEFAULT' => array(
        'controller' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
        ),
        'stadt' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][categories]',
                'lookUpTable' => array(
                    'table' => 'sys_category',
                    'id_field' => 'uid',
                    'alias_field' => 'title',
                    'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                    'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                    'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                        'strtolower' => 1,
                        'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'tags' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]',
                'lookUpTable' => array (
                  'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
                  'id_field' => 'uid',
                  'alias_field' => 'title',
                  'addWhereClause' => 'AND NOT deleted',
                  'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                  'useUniqueCache_conf' => array (
                    'strtolower' => 1,
                    'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'seite' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[@widget_0][currentPage]',
            ),
        ),

        // news archive parameters
        'archiv' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][year]',
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][month]',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'january' => '01',
                    'february' => '02',
                    'march' => '03',
                    'april' => '04',
                    'may' => '05',
                    'june' => '06',
                    'july' => '07',
                    'august' => '08',
                    'september' => '09',
                    'october' => '10',
                    'november' => '11',
                    'december' => '12',
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ),
),
// configure filenames for different pagetypes
'fileName' => array(
    'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
),
);

?>
```

I need that typoscript?

```
plugin.tx_news {
    settings {
            link {
                    skipControllerAndAction = 1
            }
    }
}
```

In the Detail-Page I check the realurl:

```
tx_realurl_exclude = 1
```

Comment: Are you sure your problem is realUrl related? What is the URL of your news detail page?

Comment: I know not sure if it is due to the expansion news.
it could also be a problem with RealUrl.
I have checked the Point: "dont show in realurl" on the deatil-site. :(

Comment: For further help it would be important to know what the URL of your news detail page is. What happens if you browse to /news-list/news-detail?

Comment: take this:
skipControllerAndAction = 0
the news is perfect. but the news-detail-page is in the url.

skipControllerAndAction = 1
url is = www.domain.org/news-list/news-detail/detail/News/test-news-name-here/


i think it is a problem with the config from realurl: tx_realurl_exclude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use detail & list plugin on the same page. Check this url: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/50489

```
lib.news = USER
lib.news {
  userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
  pluginName = Pi1
  extensionName = News
  controller = News
  settings =< plugin.tx_news.settings
  persistence =< plugin.tx_news.persistence
  view =< plugin.tx_news.view
}

lib.news_list< lib.news
lib.news_list {
  action = list
  switchableControllerActions.News.1 = list
}

lib.news_detail < lib.news
lib.news_detail {
  action = detail
  switchableControllerActions.News.1 = detail
}

[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
  lib.field_news_single < lib.news_detail
[else]
  lib.field_news_list < lib.news_list
[end]
```

Comment: ok, thanks, it works fine with the config: list and detail on the same page!

Answer (score 2):

Answer: it is not possible to exclude the current (=last) page from speaking URL.

If you are interested in technical details, you can read more in the RealURL's [notes for integrators](https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Notes-for-Integrators#excluding-pages-does-not-work).

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional followup with another solution:

Use a TypoScript condition to render dynamically the detail plugin at the list page.

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
  page.10 >
  page.10 < lib.news
[global]
```

Of course you can do a lot more fancy stuff if you need to render e.g. other content elements as well!

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
  page.10 >
  page.10 = CONTENT
  page.10 {
    table = tt_content
    pidInList = <page ID of your detail page>
    orderBy = sorting
  }
[global]
```

This will render you all content elements of the detail page on the list page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have list and single view on separate pages then extension `singleview` at https://github.com/sourcebroker/singleview does exactly what you want.

This extension uses TYPO3 build in feature "Show content from pid" which you can find in page properties. In this extension value for "Show content from pid" field is set dynamically based on `$_GET` parameter. When TYPO3 renders page with list view then `ext:singleview` checks if `$_GET` parameter has single view request. If this is true then it sets "content_from_pid" field with value of single view page uid. This way single view page with its content and layout is shown on list view page.

For TYPO3 7.6 use ext:singlenews version 1.3.