# Typo3 9.5 News - speaking Urls - remove path segment

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tx-news

is there a way to remove the "detail" page path segment from a News detail page URL.
My Configuration locks like this

```
NewsPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 152
      - 153
      - 155
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/{news_title}'
        _controller: 'News::detail'
        _arguments:
          news_title: news
    defaultController: 'News::detail'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    requirements:
      page: \d+
    aspects:
      news_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
        routeFieldName: path_segment
```

So the URLs are like this:

www.website.de/news/detail/newstitle

goal is

www.website.de/news/newstitle

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this documentation part help you it has an Routeenhancers example: https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/master/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Routing/Index.html#localized-pagination

Comment: Check this question may it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220922/typo3-7-6-tx-news-4-2-1-no-detail-name-in-realurl

Answer (score 1):

Change your setup so that list and detail view are on the same page. Otherwise I see no possibility to remove this part from the URL.
Take a look at the [description here](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/master/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/IntegrationWithTypoScript/Index.html#list-and-detail-on-the-same-page-using-typoscript).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have list and single view on separate pages then extension `singleview` at https://github.com/sourcebroker/singleview does exactly what you want.

This extension uses TYPO3 build in feature "Show content from pid" which you can find in page properties. In this extension value for "Show content from pid" field is set dynamically based on `$_GET` parameter. When TYPO3 renders page with list view then `ext:singleview` checks if `$_GET` parameter has single view request. If this is true then it sets "content_from_pid" field with value of single view page uid. This way single view page with its content and layout is shown on list view page.