# How to remove detail page slug in module tx:news in TYPO3 11?

Tags: typo3, tx-news

For SEO reasons I would like to remove the slug "detail" from the single news page of tx:news in TYPO3 11. That means that the following URL

```
domain.com/news/detail/url-of-detail-news
```

should become

```
domain.com/news/url-of-detail-news
```

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412572/typo3-9-5-news-speaking-urls-remove-path-segment) but it seems not to work in TYPO3 11. Is there any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reliable solution I know is to have list and detail view on the same page.

**Update**
From the docs, it is possible since tx_news 9.3:
https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/11.2/en-us/Tutorials/BestPractice/HideDetailPage/Index.html

Comment: It is not possible in this project as we have different list views on different pages. But thanks anyway!

Comment: From the docs, it is possible since tx_news 9.3:
https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/11.2/en-us/Tutorials/BestPractice/HideDetailPage/Index.html Hpe that still helps :)

Answer (score 1):

integrate news completely via typoscript -> see https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/11.1/en-us/Tutorials/BestPractice/IntegrationWithTypoScript/Index.html

That works fine and you can get rid of the detail-slug.

Best